# What is the corret way to call super in dynamically added methods?

Tags: python, oop, super, metaclass

I defined a metaclass which add a method named "test" to the created classes:

```
class FooMeta(type):
    
    def __new__(mcls, name, bases, attrs):
        def test(self):
            return super().test()
        attrs["test"] = test
        cls = type.__new__(mcls, name, bases, attrs)
        return cls
```

Then I create two classes using this Metaclass

```
class A(metaclass=FooMeta):
    
    pass
      

class B(A):
    
    pass
```

When I run

```
a = A()
a.test()
```

a TypeError is raised at `super().test()`:

```
super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

Which means `super()` cannot infer the parent class correctly. If I change the `super` call into

```
def __new__(mcls, name, bases, attrs):
    def test(self):
        return super(cls, self).test()
    attrs["test"] = test
    cls = type.__new__(mcls, name, bases, attrs)
    return cls
```

then the raised error becomes:

```
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'test'
```

which is expected as the parent of `A` does not implement `test` method.

---

So my question is what is the correct way to call `super()` in a dynamically added method? Should I always write `super(cls, self)` in this case? If so, it is too ugly (for python3)!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Parameterless `super()` is *very* special in Python because it triggers some behavior during code compilation time itself: Python creates an invisible `__class__` variable which is a reference to the "physical" `class` statement body were the `super()` call is embedded (it also happens if one makes direct use of the `__class__` variable inside a class method).

In this case, the "physical" class where `super()` is called is the metaclass `FooMeta` itself, not the class it is creating.

The workaround for that is to use the version of `super` which takes 2 positional arguments: the class in which it will search the immediate superclass, and the instance itself.

In Python 2 and other occasions one may prefer the parameterized use of `super`, it is normal to use the class name itself as the first parameter: at runtime, this name will be available as a global variable in the current module. That is, if `class A` would be statically coded in the source file, with a `def test(...):` method, you would use `super(A, self).test(...)` inside its body.

However, although the class name won't be available as a variable in the module defining the metaclass, you really need to pass a reference to the class as the first argument to `super`. Since the (test) method receives `self` as a reference to the instance, its class is given by either `self.__class__` or `type(self)`.

**TL;DR:** just change the super call in your dynamic method to read:

```
class FooMeta(type):
    
    def __new__(mcls, name, bases, attrs):
        def test(self):
            return super(type(self), self).test()
        attrs["test"] = test
        cls = type.__new__(mcls, name, bases, attrs)
        return cls
```